# How to join two tables in Django Admin system

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models connected to Django Admin system.
And would like to have a possibility such that by using the dropdown list, choose a specific value from the first model in a second model.

What do you think? Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: read the documentation on foreign keys

Comment: Plz edit your Q to add existing code of models.py.

Answer (score 0):

In the model definition for your first model, add a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) to the second model.

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    # ...
    second_model = models.ForeignKey(SecondModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a foreign key relationship will add this to the UI but make sure you haven’t included that field’s name in raw_id_fields

Comment: Perhaps could you improve the answer with a code sample for the FK (and a second bad sample where the field is in `raw_id_fields`)?